# Running vite build using tsconfig.build.ts

Tags: typescript, build, config, vite

### Question

Is there a way to specify which `tsconfig` file to use when running the `vite build` command?

### Problem

I am building a component library with Vite and TypeScript. My test suite is running the new Cypress component testing feature and so I've included `"src/**/*.cy.ts"` in my `tsconfig.json`. TypeScript needed some type definitions which I put in `cypress/support/components.d.ts`, and included `"cypress/**/*.ts"` in my `tsconfig.json`. Everything is working as it should, but `cypress/support/components.d.ts` is included in my `dist` directory on build.

I've gone through the docs for both Vite and Rollup, but was unable to find a way to exclude Cypress when building. Now I want to simply have a `tsconfig.build.json` that extends `tsconfig.json`, but excludes all Cypress related files. The only thing left is to tell Vite that I want to use `tsconfig.build.json` during the build process.

I imagine this would be done either through `vite.config.ts` or as a flag (`vite build --config tsconfig.build.json`).

I made a `tsconfig.build.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cypress"
  ]
}
```

But I'm not sure how to instruct Vite to use this config on build.

> typescript@4.8.4
> vite@3.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way of specifying another tsconfig file through `vite-plugin-dts`. This is the plugin I'm already using to generate types during the build process.

```js
// vite.config.ts

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'

export default defineConfig({
  build: { ... },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    dts({
      tsConfigFilePath: 'tsconfig.build.json',
    }),
  ],
})
```

#### Alternative solution

The `vite-plugin-dts` [options](https://github.com/qmhc/vite-plugin-dts#options) also allows to set excludes/includes that overrides `tsconfig.json` and makes a separate `tsconfig.build.json` redundant.

```js
// vite.config.ts

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'

export default defineConfig({
  build: { ... },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    dts({
      exclude: [
        'node_modules',
        'cypress'
      ],
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: doesnt work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a tsconfig file swapping plugin to fit our needs and I believe it would be a workaround for your problem: https://github.com/alienfast/vite-plugin-tsconfig

- allows a default `tsconfig.json`, in the end it will be put back in place
- allows specifying `workspaces` for monorepo packages to be swapped at the same time as the root

We were dealing with failed CI storybook/vite builds only to learn that vite tries to discover the nearest `tsconfig.json` at the `package.json` level regardless if one exists.  The readme explains more.

Our use case: the `tsconfig.json` in our monorepos is setup for development with the use of project references and `paths`.  We use `tsconfig.build.json` in our CI/production build scripts to build without path dependencies.  Vite seems to be coded with no knowledge of a multi-environment type of use case.

Hopefully this kind of thing is considered in vite itself and this type of hack/plugin can be archived in the future.

Answer (score -3):

`tsc` provides the build options `--project`. [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

so you just create new tsconfig file like:

```
// tsconfig.build.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["**/cypress/*"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

then modify your build script on `package.json`:

```
"scripts":{
  "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json && vite build -d",
}
```

The advantage is to write test cases can continue to enjoy type hinting and ignore the test script when your compile time.

Comment: Vite uses esbuild to tsc?